# Is the sentence "Fast food or processed foods at convenience stores, for example, causes harm…" right in terms of grammar?

Tags: plural-forms, singular

> Fast food or processed foods at convenience stores, for example,
> causes harm to the development of adolescents due to its high-fat
> levels.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

The verb *causes* should follow *fast food* subject or *processed food* or both?

Comment: I would say _from convenience stores_, but why mention them at all? Such food is equally unhealthy if bought from a supermarket or a takeaway outlet!

Comment: causes harm is not necessary. The verb harms is enough. Due to their high fat content.

Comment: The sentence is awkward, and much of it is redundant. I would reword it: "Fast or processed foods are harmful to the development of adolescents due to high fat levels".

Comment: Could we please add that high fat contents is NOT why processed food is harmful. It's mostly things like sugar, salt, refined carbo-hydrates, and SATURATED fats, like cheap oils, that cause trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *fast food or processed foods* make up a noun phrase, which is the subject. The verb follows the entire subject.
The phrase *causes harm to* could be replaced by *harms*.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence violates no rule of English grammar.

Stylistically, however, it is poor. Presumably, the point to be made is the harm to adolescents from fatty foods, but the subject of the sentence is not about fat or adolescent development. The initial focus seems to be on quickly available food rather than food high in fat. Indeed, initially it is not even clear that “fast” and processed foods are just **examples** of what is really your subject.

> Fatty foods, such as most “fast” and processed foods, harm the development of adolescents.

Now the subject of the sentence more correctly describes what you want to discuss.

You have not provided much context, but you may be trying to express a more complex thought such as

> Fatty foods harm the development of adolescents, yet they are attracted to “fast” and processed foods that tend to be high in fat.

My point is that, to be understood and to persuade, grammar is necessary but far from sufficient.